# Pandas Dataframe.to_csv Umlaute are not exported correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

```
    if os.path.isfile(dir_files+filename_with_date) == False:
        df_head = pd.DataFrame([['Artikel Nr.', 'Bestellmenge', 'gewünschte Menge Schrauben pro Tüte' ,'Kreditor Nr.', 'Kreditor']])
        df_head.to_csv(dir_files + filename_with_date, mode='a',header=False, sep=";", index=False, encoding='utf8')
```

the Umlaut characters are exportet wrong (ü=Ã¼). What can I do? I am using Python 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify the encoding as "utf-8-sig"

i.e.

```py
df_head.to_csv(dir_files + filename_with_date, mode='a',header=False, sep=";", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I thought I tried this already, but I did not replace it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using utf-16 instead of utf-8.
(Solution sponsored by ChatGPT xD)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).